# Terms of a certain recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1, a_2\dots $ be a sequence of reals such that $a_1 = a_2 = 1$, and 
$$a_{n + 2} = \frac{a_{n + 1}^3 + 1}{a_n}$$ for $n \ge 1$. It appears to be the case that all of these values are integers. How would one show that this is the case?

Comment: It's tabulated at https://oeis.org/A003818 but no indication there of whether they're all integers. If your Polish is good, you can read something about it on page 162 of http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrzej_Nowicki3/publication/273439243_Recurrence_Sequences/links/55007e470cf2d61f820dc518.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For $k=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ even $a_5$ is no integer anymore. Reconsider your conjecture.

Comment: I think the program I used to check this was incorrect as I forgot the fact that it was casting the numbers to integers. I have modified the statement of the conjecture upon fixing the program.

Answer (score 1):

The $a_n$ increase very fast. Up to $n=10$ they are all integers. What is interesting about them is that they are all products of very few large primes. See here:

[image]